# How to write test case for a component which is calling a method using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to Jest and Enzyme & facing an issue. Can someone help?
Here is my jsx file (myTemplate.jsx) :

```
export default (props) => {
  const oneSection = () => {
        return <div>Hello</div>
    };

  return (
    props.hasData ? { <div>Hey</div> } : { <div><oneSection/></div> }
   )
}
```

And this is my test file :

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import myTemplate from '../myTemplate';

 describe("template component", () => {
 const props= {
        hasData: false,
 }
 let myComponent = null;
    beforeAll(() => {
        myComponent = shallow(<myTemplate {...props}/>);
    })
    test("should render with initial state properly", () => {
        expect(myComponent).toMatchSnapshot();
    })
  })
```

Now this test case is running successfully. Snapshot is getting created with a div which has oneSection but oneSection is not getting replaced with actual html within it. Basically these lines are not getting covered :

```
 const oneSection = () => {
            return <div>Hello</div>
        };
```

How can i cover this piece of code using Jest and enzyme ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react'
import { cleanup, render } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('DMReports', () => {
  afterEach(cleanup)
  test('DMReports: hasData true', () => {
    const { container } = render(
      <DMReports hasData={true}/>,
    )
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
  test('DMReports: hasData false', () => {
    const { container, getByText } = render(
      <DMReports hasData={false}/>,
    )
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot()
    expect(getByText('Hello')).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

Comment: Is there any other way without using @testing-library/react ?

Comment: remove `beforeAll ` and init `myComponent = shallow(<myTemplate {...props}/>)` with different props

Comment: Doing that is again creating a snapshot with <oneSection /> but it is not replacing oneSection with <div>Hello</div>